Creating a PDF/A and PDF/X multistandard compliant document with scrbook and LuaLaTeX
I'm trying to create a PDF that is PDF/A- and PDF/X-compliant at the same time with LuaLaTeX and documentclass scrbook in different flavors.
So far, I found some working code. This MWE helped me produce PDFs that are compliant with PDF/A-2b or PDF/A-2u and PDF/X-4 at the same time. Though I would also like to be able to switch to PDF/X-1a and PDF/X-3, which works with snippets of this code.
This is the MWE I stitched together so far. I'm not sure what all the parts do, so I'm happy for any explanation or correction of faulty or unneeded parts. It produces a PDF compliant with PDF/A-2u (or b) and PDF/X-4 at the same time, or alternately with only a few lines of code changed with PDF/A-2u (or b) and PDF/X-1a (or 3). However, this only works with documentclass article. My question: How do I get this to work with documentclass scrbook? When using scrbook it's not compliant anymore with PDF/X. Acrobat DC warns that "Document contains actions". How do I get rid of them? I already set bookmarks to false and use NoHyper.
To get this MWE to work, you also need PSO_Uncoated_ISO12647_eci.icc from eci_offset_2009.zip from here. To switch between PDF/A and PDF/X variants, please have a look at the comments I made right before \begin{document}.
Edit: So I got the solution. See my comment below. Let's turn this into another question instead: Do you think this is a proper way to produce multistandard compliant documents for all these PDF variants (PDF/A-2b, A-2u and X-1a, x-3, X-4)? Are there better ways to do it?
MWE:
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode]
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\ifnum\luatexversion>81
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\else
\fi
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0%
\pdfminorversion=3% Setting version of pdf % must be set 3 for PDF 1.3 required by PDF/X
\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1% 

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[pdfa,bookmarks=false]{hyperref} %bookmarks are incompatible with PDF/X<6
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}[2020/06/15]
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}

\immediate\pdfobj stream attr{/N 4} file{PSO_Uncoated_ISO12647_eci.icc}
\pdfcatalog{%
  /OutputIntents [ <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S /GTS_PDFX
    /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /Info(PSO Uncoated ISO12647 (ECI))
    /OutputCondition(Offset printing, according to ISO 12647-2:2004/Amd1, OFCOM, paper type 4 = uncoated white, 115 g/m2, tone value increase curves C (CMY) and D (K))
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (Uncoated FOGRA47)
    /RegistryName(http://www.color.org)
  >>
  <<
    /Type /OutputIntent
    /S /GTS_PDFA1
    /DestOutputProfile \the\pdflastobj\space 0 R
    /Info(PSO Uncoated ISO12647 (ECI))
    /OutputCondition(Offset printing, according to ISO 12647-2:2004/Amd1, OFCOM, paper type 4 = uncoated white, 115 g/m2, tone value increase curves C (CMY) and D (K))
    /OutputConditionIdentifier (Uncoated FOGRA47)
    /RegistryName(http://www.color.org)
  >> ]
}

\makeatletter
% Bugfix of hyperref to produce CMYK links
\let\HyColor@HyperrefBorderColor\HyColor@XZeroOneThreeFour
\makeatother

\makeatletter
%we need to tell PDF/X the final format of the paper. This needs adjustment if you want graphics on the page border, called bleeding
\@tempdima=0.99626400996264009962\paperwidth
\edef\boxwd{\strip@pt\@tempdima}
\@tempdima=0.99626400996264009962\paperheight
\edef\boxht{\strip@pt\@tempdima}
\makeatother
\edef\next{%
  \protect\pdfpageattr{
    /TrimBox[0.0 0.0 \boxwd\space \boxht]
  }%
}
\next

\title{PDF/A-2b dummy document}
\author{anonymus}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Section start
% Use this section for PDF/X-1a and 3 compliance. Comment out for PDF/X-4 compliance.

\hypersetup{pdfstartpage={}}% disable openaction of hyperref for PDF/X compliance

%(mm size * 72)/25.4 = bp size
\pdfpageattr{ %fill manually
    /TrimBox [0 0 210.990 162.086]
}
\pdfinfo{ %for PDF/X
    /Title (Word vs. LaTeX) % without this copy of title pdf is not compatible with PDF/X
    /GTS_PDFXVersion (PDF/X-1:2001)
    /GTS_PDFXConformance (PDF/X-1a:2001)
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Section end

    \hypersetup{%
        pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
        pdfversionid=1,
        pdftrapped=False,
        pdfapart=2,
        pdfaconformance=U, % Change to "B" for PDF/A-2b compliance only.
        pdfstartpage={},
%       pdfxstandard={PDF/X-4}, % Comment out to switch to PDF/X-1a or 3. Use for PDF/X-4 compliance.
        urlbordercolor=red
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{NoHyper} %comment out to avoid links

\tableofcontents

\section {Title}

Text.

\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/}

\end{NoHyper} % comment out to avoid links
\end{document}


I got it. Using "\documentclass[bookmarkpackage=false]{scrbook}" it works!

May I ask what the purpose of complying with these standards is? I'm just curious. There's a lot of work on making PDFs more accessible, but that seems a completely different (and incompatible) goal.

why on earth are you using pdf 1.3 and such an old x-standard?

Well, I'd like to only deal with one document, so PDF/X and A in one. PDF/A compliance is for long-time accessibility, PDF/X to comply with what publishers or print shops ask for. And I'm not sure yet what is asked for so I'd like to have options. Though, thanks for the hint, Ulrike, I guess PDF/X-1a is not used anymore. So I'd use PDF 1.4 and PDF/X-3 instead.

yes the question is why pdf 1.3 era standards rather than pdf 1.7 and pdf/A-3 or pdf 2 and pdf/a-4 for example?

pdf 1.4 is hardly any newer than pdf 1.3,   pdf 1.7 is 2006 so already 18 years ago

Well, e.g. bod.de - a self-publishing company - explicitly asks for PDF/X-3:2002. That's v1.3, right? See here: https://www.bod.de/verlage/coverberechnung

Another example: Kindle direct publishing asks for PDF/X-1a, see here: https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/help/topic/G202145060 And: "Recent figures suggest that at least 50% of the printers out there are still actively using the PDF/X-1a standard when requesting PDF files from clients", from the video description here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9mLbX9y3es

@PsychicBirdy fair enough, depressing though:-)

Well in the pdfmanagement I support currently X-4 and above a bit. Everything else would need an update.

@DavidCarlisle Sorry, don't shoot the messenger ;-)

@UlrikeFischer Yes, I also tried that, but went on after I figured that PDF/X below 4 is not supported. Adding these older versions to pdfmanagement would be great imo, backward compatibility is always good.

sure backward compatibility is good, but one can also exagerate it. So instead of asking open source maintainers who work for free to spent their time to support a outdated standard your video says you shouldn't use anymore, ask the printer or the publisher to no longer request a standard they should no longer use.

Alright, alright. Touché! :) I just doubt that many publishers will listen though.
